# How to install CI3 Fire Starter on xampp within htdocs foler?

Tags: codeigniter, installation, xampp

How to install CI3 Fire Starter on xampp within htdocs foler?

like

htdocs/CI/my-app

and putting system and application folder in CI

then what would be value in $config['root_folder']

Comment: following these instructions https://github.com/JasonBaier/ci3-fire-starter#installation

But getting error 

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\CI\system\core\Common.php on line 601

Comment: show your folder structure

Comment: Followed all instructions as described in in installation section... placed application, system folder in xampp, created my app folder within htdocs folder and set $config['root_folder'] = 'htdocs/my-app-dir-name'. IT IS WORKING